# Not able to connect test controller with visual studio team services

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-devops, microsoft-test-manager

I am trying to setup lab environment in MTM and for that when i am setting up test controller version number is 15.0 with visual studio team services i am getting "failed to configure tfs team project collection" error and in the logs "Timedout while waiting for service Visual Studio Test Controller to go to state Running. Current status is Stopped" displayed.

I tried even removing environment given in below  link  -https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dc5607c1-b563-4503-857e-f3b5ce781cb8/test-controller-vs20124-just-wont-configure?forum=vstest

My service user is in local admin group.

Any help would be appreciated .

Thanks

Comment: If it's timeout error, check firewall and server url.

Comment: @qxg i am getting "Timedout while waiting for service Visual Studio Test Controller to go to state Running. Current status is Stopped
E, 2017/11/25, 18:51:44.318, Got Exception : Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.ConfigToolException: Could not complete operation as the timeout expired."  Exception  .i checked my firewall and server url also. please help

Answer (score 1):

VSTS does not support lab management features as they are deprecated -- TFS 2018 dropped support for it, as well.

VSTS build/release has tasks for deploying test agents and running functional tests across your test agents.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .just one more point i need to display result in MTM,can i do without using lab environment ?Thanks for your help